# IIS7 ASP - Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed

Tags: iis-7, sql, asp-classic

Getting a strange error for an old site I am trying to move to a new server - The new server is Win2008 64bit with IIS7.

This site is working perfectly on an IIS6 Win2003 server, but I have just moved it over and run the site but I get the following error

```
Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.
```

From looking around people seem to to just say enable 32 bit applications in the App pool and it will be fine?  Unfortunately I did this and it didn't work?  It seems to be falling over here

```
'*************************************************************************
'Open Database Connection
'*************************************************************************
function openDB()
    on error resume next
    set connTemp = server.createobject("adodb.connection")
    connTemp.Open connString
    if err.number <> 0 then
        dim errMsg
        errMsg = "" _
            & "<b>Module :</b> scripts/_INCappDBConn_.asp : openDB()<br /><br />" _
            & "<b>Number :</b> " & err.number & "<br /><br />" _
            & "<b>Page :</b> "   & Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO") & "<br /><br />" _
            & "<b>Desc :</b> "   & err.Description
        call errorDB("",errMsg)
    end if
    on error goto 0
    if UCase(dbLocked) = "Y" then
        call errorDB("<b>" & LangText("ErrStoreClosed","") & "</b>","")
        closeDB()
    end if
end function
```

Just wondering if anyone can shed any light on what is going in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that this is fairly basic - but did you start by making sure that in IIS has ASP installed?  Classic ASP isn't installed by default on IIS7.  Go to Programs and Features in Control Panel and click Turn Windows features on and off. Navigate down the tree of features and make sure ASP is checked.

If you haven't already gone down this path - it's probably the issue.

Comment: By the way, if this turns out to be the issue there are a few other things.  You will need to add an application pool for classic ASP.  When you create it set .Net Framework Version to "No Managed Code" and the Managed Pipeline mode to "Classic"... While "checking my work" on this I came across this article which may help you step by step: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/472/how-to-install-aspnet-11-with-iis7-on-vista-and-windows-2008/  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you will be shocked when I suggest that not all Microsoft applications and services work correctly in 64-bit mode...  Just in case this might be a factor in your environment, see if there is an option to run this database connection in a 32-bit mode.  For example, I got your exact error in a Visual Studio project that used a VB .NET script, and after changing the VS Project property, Run64BitRuntime, to be 'False', meaning run in 32-bit = 'True'.  Then, magically, the error disappeared  :  )  I know you mentioned you changed a setting in the Application pool, but the error might occur before then, at run time when the database connection is made.  Testing it outside of IIS might confirm or eliminate this as an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issues. Checked all the marks, and based on the response from Marie Kelly did the following :
in IIS7 goto Application Pool, select the correct application pool, click on 
Advanced Settings and set "Enable 32-Bit Applications" =>True.